# CSS: When are empty anonymous block boxes removed?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

According to the [CSS Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) anonymous block boxes are created when a block container box has both inline and block content.

The example the specification uses is

```
<DIV>
Some text
<P>More text</P>
</DIV>
```

Chrome renders this as:

`Some text
More text`

However, given:

```
<DIV>
[5 spaces followed by newline]
<P>Some text</P>
</DIV>
```

Chrome renders this as:

`Some text`

In other words, the line containing spaces is eliminated.

I'm confused about the order in which anonymous block boxes are created and the order in which the [CSS white-space specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) is applied.

a) If we assume that the anonymous block box is created first, we have

```
<DIV>
<anonymous_block>[5 spaces followed by newline]</anonymous_block>
<P>Some text</P>
</DIV>
```

b) Then, during layout of the anonymous block, we find that the white-space model first reduces the entire content to a single space. A single line is created containing this space.

c) This rule causes the space to be eliminated:
"If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is also removed."

d) At this point we have a zero width line but its height (if I understand the css model correctly) is that of the font.

Therefore, I would expect an empty line with the font's height to appear before the text.

Since this is not the case, which of the steps above is incorrect? Please be specific about how the CSS specification leads to the observed behavior.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with CSS specifications, It's the way HTML is parsed: any space or new line between two blocks will be ignored, unless both of them are inline blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the answer is in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) portion of the CSS2 specification, which reads:

"Line boxes are created as needed to hold inline-level content within an inline formatting context. Line boxes that contain no text, no preserved white space, no inline elements with non-zero margins, padding, or borders, and no other in-flow content (such as images, inline blocks or inline tables), and do not end with a preserved newline must be treated as zero-height line boxes for the purposes of determining the positions of any elements inside of them, and must be treated as not existing for any other purpose."

The above paragraph explains the observed behavior. [There is also another part of the spec, on [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), which refers to the above paragraph. I'm mentioning this because readers that come across this answer may find it useful.]

Comment: This is correct. Note that this has several related effects, such as when floating (therefore removing from the flow) the only content of a line, or setting a replaced inline element to `display:block` which is often used to remove the gap under images.

Answer (score 1):

In a `block` context, whitespaces are ignored.

In an `inline` or `inline-block` context, whitespaces are trim to a single space.

So, your 5 space characters and the newline character don't trigger the creation of an anonymous block, because the `<p>` sets the inner of the `<div>` in a block context

About your question. I think step a) is incorrect. The steps seem to be called in a different order and by that change the interpretation.

Comment: Could you point to where it says this in the CSS specification?

Comment: unfortunately I can't. It's a matter of my experience.

Comment: The CSS specification explains this behavior here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level